# Facebook Comments: не отображается первый добавленный комментарий

Tags: facebook-widgets, facebook, комментарии

Добавил на сайт код комментариев от Facebook. Код виджета взял из [документации](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/). Добавляю его после тега *body*.

Проблема в том, что если на странице еще не было ни одного комментария, то при их добавлении они не отображаются до тех пор, пока ее не обновить. При этом если комментарии уже были, то виджет работает как и ожидается - комментарий сразу появляется ниже.